# Mango tree post efflorescence… what now?

Tags: pruning, flowering, mango

Healthy young mango grew a large efflorescence, but didn’t ultimately produce fruit. That’s ok! But now there’s a big “leftover” growth atop the primary trunk, and some smaller new growth coming up alongside it. Should I prune the leftover efflorescence so as to favor the new growth? Leave it alone and let nature take its course?

[image: Picture detailing 'leftover' growth and new growth]

Comment: We really need a picture in order to give you a good answer

Comment: Reasonable! Added a picture

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can cut that down, give the new branches more space and nutrition :)